# RSpec `undefined method` .. `for proc` in a very-simple spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Can someone help me figure out why the line marked `#works` works, but the line marked `#causes error` causes error? (This is Rails 3.2.6 with rspec-rails 2.11.0)

The error: `undefined method 'more_things=' for #<Proc:0x007fbd23d0b960> (NoMethodError)`

spec:

```
describe User do

  subject { User.new }

  it "has no something" do
    User.new.more_things = "#works"        #works
    subject.something.should be_empty      #works
  end

  describe "#more_things" do
    User.new.more_things = "#works"        #works
    subject.more_things = "#causes error"  #causes error
  end

end
```

model:

```
class User

  def something
    []
  end

  def more_things=(value)

  end

end
```

I tried putting another `subject { User.new }` inside `describe "#more_things" do` thinking that it could be some kind of scope problem, but that did not help (it's not a scope problem because `subject` *does* return something - a `Proc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. Slow me. It works when it is in an `it` block (or in a `before`/`after` block):

```
describe "#more_things" do
  User.new.more_things = "#works"        #works
  subject.more_things = "#causes error"  #causes error
  it "should work now" do
    subject.more_things = "#works now"   #works
  end
end
```

I guess I should always remember *it is the subject* :)

Comment: I forget the `it` block ALL the time! It's the first thing I look for now if my rspec is erroring

Comment: Yeah, describe blocks should only contain "it", "before" blocks, not the actual content/code you want run